# ReactJS - large video files makes computer freeze after npm start

Tags: reactjs, video, npm, webpack, large-files

I've got my small react web app that runs with no problem with five low quality video.
But once I add multiple large high quality video files and I start the app, my laptop freezes and I need to manually shut it down.

```
    <video width="90%" height="90%" margin="auto" controls>
      <source src={require(('../videos/' + props.movie + ".mp4"))} type="video/mp4" alt= "video" />
    </video>
```

My videos folder is on my src folder, Any advice?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to load you video files inside componentDidMount() lifycycle method when component is mounted.

Comment: Nope, didn't work


`componentDidMount() {
    const videos = importAll(require.context('./videos', false, /\.mp4$/));
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
    <video width="90%" height="90%" margin="auto" controls>
          <source src={ props.movie } type="video/mp4" alt= "video" />
        </video>`